# Pop up state directly from coldstart

Tags: android, performance, ionic-framework, webrtc, peerjs

I've built a Cordova [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.everycrave.livewire) using the ionic framework. It is build using [Peer JS](http://peerjs.com/) and i need the app to open a state from cold start quickly whenever my peer receives an incoming call, kind of like the phone app opens the incoming call activity when we receive a call.

Currently I'm using [ionic push notifications](http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/push-full-setup) to open the state on click of the notification but that takes too long and loads from the splash screen onwards.

Is there a way to kind of pop open my state containing the receive call code into the foreground quickly

Comment: Have you looked at deep linking? http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/

Comment: @amuramoto yes i have, but it still loads the app from the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova, the hack that i came up with was,

First, separate the incoming call code into a html page with the required javascript code.

Next, send a notification with a specific payload, then in the onRecieve method in the phonegap push plugin, I check the payload, if it matches the specific payload and if the app is killed, i use an intent to open the main activity which contains the cordova webview, I load the html page here based on the intent.

This makes it appear as if the app "pops open".