# WebRTC video call and IONIC, call when app runs in background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, webrtc, twilio

I made an application using twilio, webRTC and ionic, and the video call is working. However, is it possible to make the video call when the app runs in background? I couldn't come up with a solution with ionic.

Comment: i came up with an ugly hack here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252461/pop-up-state-directly-from-coldstart

Comment: if you separate the concern how are you planning to receive the calls when the app is open and the navigation is on one of the pages which has no listening mode to the incoming call?? @Akil

Comment: when the app is open, there is a controller that creates a peer and listens for an incoming call that arrives in any page, when a call occurs, then the state is redirected to the specified state.
                                                



In my case when the app is killed, the peer is destroyed and there is no code listening for an incoming call, so i use a notification to open the app to a single HTML page separated from the rest of the app, this page resends the call back and the orginal caller automatically "accepts" the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a landing page upon login which has all the token grant and initialization of [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) so that once a user logs in. It is already on listening mode. Then, i handled the opening of push to actually just redirect to that particular landing page. In my case, the landing page is `app.onlineUsers`

```
         var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData.action));
        if (jsonData.action) {
            if (jsonData.action.actionID == "IdAccept") {
                $state.go('app.onlineUsers');
                //custom code executes
            } else if (jsonData.action.actionID == "IdReject") {
                alert('rejected');
            }
        }
    };
    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
        // alert(ids);
        did = ids.userId;
        $sessionStorage.DID = did;
        $localStorage.DID = did;
        // alert(" player_id: "+$localStorage.DID);
    });
    // TODO: Update with your OneSignal AppId and googleProjectNumber before running.
    window.plugins.OneSignal.startInit("appId", "googleProjectNumber")
 .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback).handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
            $state.go('app.onlineUsers');
            // alert("Notification received:\n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            // console.log('Did I receive a notification: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        }).inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None).endInit();
```